# What is your favorite beer & food pairing?

Tags: pairing

Certain beers tend to go better with certain foods.

What beer & food do you like to enjoy together?

Answer (score 1):

My two favorite pairings are nice IPA and some Indian food and pale ale + bbq pork (ribs or shoulder).

Comment: sounds tasty,, too bad i don't eat pork..

Comment: I think a barbecue beef brisket and a pale ale would also be a very nice pairing :)

Comment: Why?  What are the characteristics that make this a good pairing?

Comment: @Xander I think that the sweetness of the barbecue sauce (especially a more pork oriented bbq sauce) is nicely countered, but not overwhelmed by the slight bitterness of a pale ale.

Answer (score 1):

A black malt goes well with the char of a good steak, and would also go well with a rich, chocolaty dessert.

A malty red ale would pair nicely with any smokey BBQ or roasted meat.

Wheat beers pair very well with more delicate dishes such as seafood, sushi, or shellfish.

Lastly, I find IPA's that aren't incredibly hoppy emphasize the spiciness of Mexican dishes, jerk chicken, or sausage. An IPA that is punch-in-the-mouth-hoppy will overpower just about any dish though.

---

While technically not a pairing, if you've never experienced a [beer milkshake](http://www.manmadediy.com/users/chris/posts/2127-how-to-make-your-own-beer-milkshakes-at-home), I highly recommend them.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the Czech Republic, where I live, the favorite with-beer-food would be something that we call 'vepřo knedlo zelo'.

That means like(our special type of) dumplings, pork and cabbage. It tastes wonderful... give it a look at [google images](https://www.google.cz/search?q=vep%C5%99o%20knedlo%20zelo&rlz=1C1CHYD_csCZ568CZ569&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=GEjJVMa5EcfaPPSLgZAE&ved=0CB8QsAQ).

Well, the quality of the Czech main-stream beer went low, so the best might be 'Podkováň', which is very difficult to buy even here in CR.

Comment: i heard pivovar podkováň cLosed down,,

Comment: they closed 2007 and reopened 2011 :D